# How to empty a Heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails 3 webapp on Heroku. How do I empty the database?

Answer (score 727, accepted):

To drop the database, if you are using `SHARED_DATABASE_URL`:

```
$ heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
```

Now to **recreate** the database with nothing in it:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

To **populate** the database with your seed data:

```
$ heroku run rake db:seed
```

---OR---

You can combine the last two (**migrate & seed**) into one action by executing this:

```
$ heroku run rake db:setup
```

**Edit** 2014-04-18: `rake db:setup` doesn't work with Rails 4, it fails with a `Couldn't create database error`.

**Edit** 2014-10-09: You can use `rake db:setup` with Rails 4. It does give you a `Couldn't create database` error (because the database was already created using the `heroku pg:reset` command). But it also loads your database schema and your seeds after the error message.

You can do this with pretty much any rake command, but there are exceptions. For example, `db:reset` doesn't work via `heroku run rake`. You have to use `pg:reset` instead.

More information can be found in Heroku's documentation:

[Running Rake Commands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake)

[Reset Postgres DB](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-reset)

Comment: when yous say `your see data` what do you mean? is there a way I can add default data into the DB?

Comment: I'm using heroku free account and it tells me that i am not the owner of the DB

Comment: @Abra: I meant 'seed data'. Also, db:drop doesn't work in heroku. Corrected instructions to use the proper beginning command.

Comment: 'Seed data' is data you have set up to be placed in your database for testing. It's usually defined in db/seeds.rb

Comment: Thank you. Actually, "heroku pg:reset --db SHARED_DATABASE_URL" did the trick. But you got me going in the right direction.

Comment: @JayGodse Heroku now says `SHARED_DATABASE_URL is deprecated, please use SHARED_DATABASE`

Comment: Actually you should be checking in your schema.rb and you should use:
rake db:schema:load

Comment: DATABASE_URL will generally work more than SHARED_DATABASE_URL.

Comment: They have changed it again now is `heroku pg:reset DATABASE`

Comment: To save a couple of seconds of time, use `heroku pg:reset DATABASE --confirm appname`

Comment: For the sake of completeness: To get the value for DATABASE run `heroku pg:info`

Comment: `rake db:setup` seems disallowed now - you'll need to run `migrate` and `seed` separately instead.

Comment: They have changed it again. The command that worked for me now is `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL`

Comment: `heroku run rake db:migrate db:seed` that is guaranteed to work just like `rake db:setup` used to work. You can chain commands like this to save time.

Comment: you can also try to reset DB using this gem https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db, in each table view you can truncate table, or you can truncate DB using SQL

Comment: @AlanDavidGarcia It didn't change, it's just that the answer is misleading. The `DATABASE` should actually be `<database>`, which is a placeholder for the database name. The default database is named `DATABASE_URL` which you can see if you run `heroku pg:info`, but you can actually add more databases if you like, and manage them separately.

Comment: Thank you!  Only needed `heroku pg:reset` and then follow the prompts on my end.

Comment: As of 2022 (only a couple more weeks to go before free goes away) @guero64 is correct

Answer (score 103):

Heroku has deprecated the `--db` option now, so now use:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm {the name of your app}
```

It's a little confusing because you use the literal text `SHARED_DATABASE` but where I have written `{the name of your app}` substitute the name of your app.  For example, if your app is called my_great_app then you use:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm my_great_app
```

Comment: if you just paste skip the bit after (and including) the -- heroku will tell you what to type..

Comment: useful command to get the name of your postgres database on heroku : heroku config | grep HEROKU_POSTGRESQL

Comment: "you use the literal text SHARED_DATABASE" ?  You are using DATABASE_URL in your code samples.  Do you mean that?

Comment: Nope. I was referring to the other answer's use of the words `SHARED_DATABASE`

Answer (score 72):

**To drop the database:**

```
$ heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE --confirm NAME_OF_THE_APP
```

**To recreate the database:**

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

**To seed the database:**

```
$ heroku run rake db:seed
```

**Final step

```
$ heroku restart
```

Comment: I prefer this answer over any else's. This works perfectly in my scenario on Heroku, I believe it is highly under voted!

Comment: It might be because heroku changed the syntax of these commands recently.

Comment: 'heroku restart' was the one key piece I was missing.  Thanks.

Comment: `heroku run rake db:migrate` no longer recreates the database

Answer (score 49):

The current, ie. 2017 way to do this is:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-reset

Comment: Agreed. The current way to re-populate the database is: `heroku run rake db:migrate db:seed`

Answer (score 14):

Now the command is

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm your_app_name
```

this way you can specify which app's db you want to reset.
Then you can run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate 
heroku run rake db:seed
```

or direct for both above commands

```
heroku run rake db:setup
```

And now final step to restart your app

```
heroku restart
```

Comment: Restarting might not be necessary but good point giving it a mention.

Answer (score 11):

I contacted Heroku support, and they confirmed that it is a bug with the latest gem (I am using heroku-2.26.2)

> Charlie - we are aware of this issue with the 'heroku' gem and are
>   working to fix it.
>
> Here's the issue if you care to follow-along -
>   https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/356
>
> Downgrading to an earlier version of the 'heroku' gem should help. I've been using v2.25.0 for most of today without issue.

Downgrade with the following commands:

```
gem uninstall heroku

gem install heroku --version 2.25.0
```

If you already have multiple gems installed, you may be presented with:

> ```
> Select gem to uninstall:
>  1. heroku-2.25.0
>  2. heroku-2.26.2
>  3. All versions
> ```

Just uninstall #2 and rerun the command. Joy!

Comment: All the gems have been deprecated now, you need to get rid of them and install the Heroku toolbelt. https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

Answer (score 9):

The *complete* answer is (for users with multi-db):

**heroku pg:info** - which outputs

> === **HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED** <-- this is DB
>   Plan         Basic
>   Status       available

**heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED --confirm app_name**

More information found in: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Answer (score 8):

Now it's diffrent with heroku. Try:
    heroku pg:reset DATABASE --confirm

Comment: For some apps you still need to use SHARED_DATABASE

Answer (score 8):

Now it's also possible to reset the database through their web interface.

Go to [dashboard.heroku.com](https://dashboard.heroku.com) select your app and then you'll find the database under the add-ons category, click on it and then you can reset the database.

[image: Reset Heroku Database]

Answer (score 7):

Today the command

```
heroku pg:reset --db SHARED_DATABASE_URL
```

not working for shared plans, I'm resolve using

```
heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE
```

Answer (score 6):

Check your heroku version. I just updated mine to 2.29.0, as follows:

```
heroku --version
#=> heroku-gem/2.29.0 (x86_64-linux) ruby/1.9.3
```

Now you can run:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE --confirm YOUR_APP_NAME
```

Then create your database and seed it in a single command:

```
heroku run rake db:setup
```

Now restart and try your app:

```
heroku restart
heroku open
```

Answer (score 6):

Login to your DB using
`heroku pg:psql` and type the following commands:

```
drop schema public cascade;
create schema public;
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you prefer to use Heroku Web-site:

1. Go to https://postgres.heroku.com/databases
2. Select the database you want to reset
3. Click on a settings button in the right upper corner
4. Click "Reset Database" as shown below:
5. type in "RESET" and press ok

[image: heroku database reset]

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me.
1.clear db.

```
heroku pg:reset --app YOUR_APP
```

After running that you will have to type in your app name again to confirm.

2.migrate db to recreate.

```
heroku run rake db:migrate  --app YOUR_APP
```

3.add seed data to db.

```
heroku run rake db:seed --app YOUR_APP
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to reset your PostgreSQL database and set it back up, use:

```
heroku apps
```

to list your applications on Heroku. Find the name of your current application (`application_name`). Then run

```
heroku config | grep POSTGRESQL
```

to get the name of your databases. An example could be

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL
```

Finally, given `application_name` and `database_url`, you should run

```
heroku pg:reset `database_url` --confirm `application_name`
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku restart
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged in from the console, this will do the job in the latest heroku toolbelt,

heroku pg:reset --confirm database-name

Answer (score 0):

I always do this with the one-liner 'heroku pg:reset DATABASE'.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for you issue will be

```
heroku pg:reset -r heroku  --confirm your_heroku_app_name
```

> --confirm your_heroku_app_name

is not required, but terminal always ask me do that command.

After that command you will be have pure db, without structure and stuff, after that you can run

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load -r heroku
```

or

```
heroku run rake db:migrate -r heroku
```