# How to rake db:drop and rake db:create on Heroku?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, rake

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to empty DB in heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820549/how-to-empty-db-in-heroku)

I have a Postgres database on Heroku.  It is one of the free beta ones.  Locally, when testing, I often run rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate as a way to reset the database.

However, when I try to run this on Heroku, I get the error:

```
Couldn't drop mydatabaseid : #<PG::Error: FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
  DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

Uh, ok, so how am I supposed to completely reset my database, migrations and everything?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The `pg:reset` command will recreate the database for you. Example usage:

```
$ heroku config | grep POSTGRESQL
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL: postgres://somedatabaseurl
$ heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL
!    WARNING: Destructive Action
!    This command will affect the app: myappname
!    To proceed, type "myappname" or re-run this command with --confirm
> myappname
Resetting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL (DATABASE_URL)... done
```

The `db:reset` command would try to drop the database, which is not something that Heroku's permissions allow.

Comment: Great!... where'd you find that? I read their docs here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Comment: In my brain somewhere - no idea where.

Comment: Here is Heroku documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone who skipped over the above link, you want to run **`heroku pg:reset`** at the command line, not `heroku run rake pg:reset` or anything like that.

Comment: Just a small update: in order to reset `postgres` database, you are required to enter `name` of database.

Comment: This worked for me: `heroku config | grep POSTGRESQL` - getting the name of database e.g. `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE_URL` and then running `heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE_URL`

Comment: Heroku asks you to confirm. For one line resetting try heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL --confirm <appname>

Comment: Note that after you do the above, you will have to do `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Comment: `heroku run rake pg:drop` doesn't work for me.

Comment: For new apps, the db is already created by heroku and you don't need to run db:setup, just run db:migrate

Comment: When I tried the above options using database name I got an error saying that `Valid options are: DATABASE_URL`. So I entered `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL` and it worked just fine.

Comment: don't forget --app as some implementations of the CLI require that:  `heroku config --app <name_of_app> | grep POSTGRESQL`