# Rails 4 + Postrges Heroku: How can I clear all the data for a specific model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am using Heroku postgresql with my Rails 4 app.

My app has a Photo model which currently has 100 photos. I want to start over, deleting all of the existing photos so that the next uploaded photo will have photo_id: 1.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990104/how-to-rake-dbdrop-and-rake-dbcreate-on-heroku) but it appears that this would reset the entire database (meaning that *all* of my models would be reset instead of just the Photo model)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to heroku rails console and run:

```
Photo.destroy_all
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE table_name RESTART IDENTITY")
```

`table_name` is name of table which stores photos.