# ruby on rails Heroku migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I run $ heroku run rake db:migrate, I get "Multiple migrations have the name CreateScreencasts".

Or I get: Multiple migrations have the version number 20121121161626

Is there a way to delete migrations on Heroku?

(My app code only has one)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one migration in your git repo, you should have only one migration in your heroku repo.

It may be because you deleted an old migration which is still registered in the heroku database. Is it acceptable for you to reset your heroku database ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have troubles with migrations on heroku use this

```
heroku run bash --app appname
```

Then you are in a terminal on the server it self. And you can run all the rails rake commands

You can for instance do this

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful and it's already been answered

[How to empty DB in heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820549/how-to-empty-db-in-heroku)

Basically you'd run

To drop the database, if you are using SHARED_DATABASE_URL:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```

To recreate the database with nothing in it:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```