# Rake db:reset 'user does not have CONNECT privilege'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

So I'm using Heroku Postgres in my Rails app, but I'm not hosting my app on Heroku itself. I used the Active Record connection details from Heroku in my database.yml, and it looks like this:

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
pool: 5
database: [database]
username: [username]
password: [password]
host: ec2-54-227-243-78.compute-1.amazonaws.com
port: 5432
```

However, now I'm trying to rake db:migrate my app so the database gets all set up with my models. Running that command doesn't do anything, so I tried `rake db:reset` and I get this:

```
Couldn't drop df2cokjfj0k4vu : #<PG::Error: FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"                                                                  
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

> df2cokjfj0k4vu already exists
>   -- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
>      -> 1.3997s
>   -- assume_migrated_upto_version(20130924040351, ["/home/action/braindb/db/migrate"])
>      -> 0.0882s

Any idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm still pretty new to Rails so sometimes I forget how to get my Postgres database setup properly when migrating hosts.

Answer (score 70):

Use `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` instead as noted in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake

You cannot drop databases in Heroku with `rake db:reset` because user has no privileges.

Comment: You must specify the database when using heroku pg:reset

Comment: heroku pg:reset DATABASE 

Good instructions for resetting DB on Heroku: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820549/how-to-empty-db-in-heroku

Comment: Also note that you need to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` afterwards because reset doesn't really mean reset, it just means drop.

Comment: I got this error on a completely fresh heroku app. Seems odd?

Answer (score 6):

You [can't drop your PG database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake) on Heroku.

Comment: Then could you suggest what I might need to do to migrate and get the tables created?

Comment: `heroku run rake db:migrate` doesn't do anything?  You can "go nuclear" with `heroku rake run db:schema:load` which will re-load the full schema.

Comment: Wait, are you using the Heroku DB from your local machine?  If so, remove the `heroku` from in front of the commands and just run `rake db:schema:load`.

Comment: `rake db:schema:load` seems to have worked, but `rake db:migrate` still does nothing. I'll keep looking around. Thanks for the help, Nick.

Comment: `db:schema:load` will always apply the `schema.rb` file.  `db:migrate` will apply the migrations in `/db/migrate` that haven't been applied (by date, according to the `schema_migrations` table in the database itself.  If the database thinks it ran the migration (by having a date >= the latest migration) it won't run any, even if you change the latest migration.  Which is why you should never change a migration once it's committed/has been run.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

I recently had this problem and resolved it through the following steps.

1. `heroku pg --help` gets the name of commands for using postgres
2. `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` # resets the db
3. Answer the prompt to confirm

Answer (score 5):

Like others I had a similar problem but running `pg:reset` did not help: that's where I ran into the `user does not have CONNECT privilege` issue.

1) `heroku pg:reset` you will be prompted to enter the project name to confirm.

2) From [Heroku's docs](https://help.heroku.com/63D7ALXT/why-am-i-seeing-user-does-not-have-connect-privilege-error-with-heroku-postgres-on-review-apps) run `heroku rake db:schema:load`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by running:

`heroku pg:reset DATABASE`

(note: must specify DATABASE as above)

Answer (score 3):

If you got this because you were running `rake db:create`, instead, simply skip to the migration. For whatever reason, postgresql on heroku doesn't require the `rake db:create` step as may be required on local installations.

In other words, instead of

```sh
heroku run rake db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

run this instead

```sh
heroku run rake db:migrate db:seed
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to me was to just go straight to migration because the database is already created (**don't go on "heroku run rails db:create"**)

```
heroku run rails db:migrate -a YOURAPPNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

For one of my apps, upgrading to the first paid tier of a Heroku database seemed to work for me: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups#provision-new-plan

Reason was that 'heroku pg:info' revealed that I was over my row limit as shown here:
Rows:        12392/10000 (Write access revoked)