# how to relaunch rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4

My app runs properly locally and has a crash when it runs on Heroku.  The app does fine until I run a new_post_path call. I tried git push to see if a change to the new.html.erb file or the _form.html.erb file was the issue - but I think during the last push to heroku - my database may have taken a hit.  At the time I was adding a t.text field (longtext) and it seems to be the issue.

So I wanted to roll back or totally re-start at heroku.  But I have not found anyway to do it.  Since this is not near production yet. Is there anyway to just create a new instance at heroku and push up to it?

Again, local version runs perfect.  Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there are several ways to handle this problem

## restarting heroku

Run `$ heroku restart` in the rails dir. Sometimes I believe in magic.

## debugging

Use `$ heroku log` to debug what is causing the error.

## migrate database

Perhaps you made a database change in local rails, while heroku rails didn't.

Run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

## drop database and remigrate database

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820549/how-to-empty-db-in-heroku). Sometimes old migration might be in conflict with current migration. Do a clean migration, if the data in your database isn't important.

## recreate heroku instance

run `$ heroku apps:destroy –app appname` and replace `appname` with your appname. Then delete the current `heroku` remote repository location from git. `git remote rm heroku`. Then recreate heroku. run `$ heroku create`. go through pushing your code and migrating database like usual.

Answer (score 0):

Relaunching might be the least of your problems, so I suggest a few things:

1. Review this [Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases) on releases, including the Heroku rollback feature.
2. Add the [PG Backups](https://addons.heroku.com/pgbackups) add-on to your app.
3. I also recommend using something like the [exception_notification](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) gem in combination with the SendGrid add-on, so that you can get an email with details on the error as well.