# Cannot use heroku run rake db:migrate in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
sahilrd07:~/workspace/sample2 (filling-in-layout) $ heroku run rake db:drop
Running rake db:drop on limitless-coast-42827... up, run.4760
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Sass::Script
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Heroku apps do not have permission to drop and create databases.

Answer (score 0):

You should enter your Heroku server and run the command there:

```
$ heroku console
Ruby console for heroku-project-name
>> ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:table_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820549/how-to-empty-db-in-heroku), you can also drop the db from your heroku dashboard. From the linked post:

> Now it's also possible to reset the database through their web interface.
>
> Go to dashboard.heroku.com select your app and then you'll find the database under the add-ons category, click on it and then you can reset the database.

[image]